# Expectation of random vector constrained to a linear subspace

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose a random vector $\mathbf{X}$ takes value in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but is always constrained to a vector subspace of $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, how can I prove that it's expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}]$ is also constrained to that same subspace? This seems completely obvious, $\mathbf{X}$ has no probability density outside $W$, so how can $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}]$ be anywhere else but inside $W$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $y$ is orthogonal to that subspace then $ \langle y, EX \rangle =E\langle y, X \rangle=E0=0$. This implies that $EX$ lies in that subspace. [I am using the fact that $(M^{\perp})^{\perp}=M$].